# How to paint country poligon on google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps

How to paint country poligon or country border line on google maps?
Now i have only

```
    MapView mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);       

    MapController mapController = mapView.getController();
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps Javascript API has something called `Overlays`, where you can add `Polygon` overlays to your map. But I am not sure whether this is available for Android as well. Here is the [link](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/overlays.html#Polygons_Overview) if you would like to explore more on that.

Comment: In Google Maps Javascript API I've seen method. Bun not seen in Google Maps API for Android OS :-(

Answer (score 0):

one suggestion could be to load the map into Webview and use this **Google Polygons V3**  Javascript Code http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#polygons_v3  to draw Polygon on your desired location